# Как выбрать ссылку по контенту?

Tags: javascript

### Пример

Как реализовать через JavaScript клик по ссылке, содержащей слово «hello».

Пробовал такой вариант:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('my-id').click();
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">
  <span id="my-id">hello</span>
</a>
```

Работает, но нужен вариант, который выбирает ссылку по заданному слову.

Comment: Получаем массив элементов по Тэгу `a`, проверяем их `innerHTML` на наличие нужного слова.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нативными способами только через `xpath`; но это, как мне кажется, «пляски с бубнами» — всегда проще выборку делать по CSS-селектору.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так можно.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i].getAttribute('href');
    if (link.indexOf('word') !== -1) {
      links[i].click();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span  id="z-1">sfdsdffsd</span></a>
<a href="#"><span  id="z-1">sfdsdffsd</span></a>
<a href="http://javascript.ru/forum/word"><span  id="z-1">sfdsdffsd dasdsaddsafdsf</span></a>
<a href="#"><span  id="z-1">sfdsdffsd</span></a>
<a href="#"><span  id="z-1">sfdsdffsd</span></a>
<a href="#"><span  id="z-1">sfdsdffsd</span></a>
```

Comment: KAGG Design. Хороший вариант, но слово word должно быть в ссылке. например http://javascript.ru/word или http://word.javascript.ru/forum

Comment: А, ну это не очень четко прозвучало. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Внес изменение.

Comment: KAGG Design. Спасибо! Все работает! А если несколько ссылок с word то он начинает открывать все. Можно ли жестко указать количество открываемых ссылок? Допустим если с словом word 10 ссылок, но нужно открыть 2

Comment: Ну там же цикл есть в моем коде, воткните в него счетчик

Comment: KAGG Design Подскажите как пожалуйста. А то я в JS новичок :( Не соображу никак..